# Did Jesus' body decompose to any extent?

Tags: greek, acts, resurrection

Acts 2:27 (NRSV)

> 27 For you will not abandon my soul to Hades, or let your Holy One experience corruption.
>
> ὅτι οὐκ ἐγκαταλείψεις τὴν ψυχήν μου εἰς ᾅδην οὐδὲ δώσεις τὸν ὅσιόν σου ἰδεῖν διαφθοράν.

I see in the Greek the NRSV translates ἰδεῖν (to see, aorist infinitive) as "to experience", which somewhat begs the question.

In some traditions non-decomposition of holy people is a treasured belief, and so I wonder if those traditions are affecting the usual interpretation that Jesus' body did not decay at all.

The problem with this is without bodily decay, what difference is there between death and a form of suspended animation?  If the brain and heart have merely stopped with no other decomposition beginning, effectively paused, then resurrection could be done with something akin to a defibrillator.

Does the text necessitate the idea of no decomposition at all?  Or does it leave open the possibility that the body of Jesus would have suffered the usual effects of being dead in a hot climate for 30-some hours?

Comment: This Q was previously closed but was a near-duplicate for a newer question that was slightly higher quality, so I've *merged* the answers in - a little unorthodox, but seemed like the best direction. Figured that you probably wouldn't mind as it 'rescues' your own Answer to the Q which may receive more votes over there.